# jQuery not working the second time with dynamic audio playlist

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html5-audio, audio-streaming, playlist

I want to be able to play uploaded songs from a dynamic created folders(source) similar to reverb, soudcloud. This is a rails App with below generated html source code.

Original tutorial by Brad Traversy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTwwX__o01M

**Problem is only the latest uploaded song within the first nested plays.The rest are not playing. I think jQuery is not working on the subsequent songs since the buttons are inactive.
Any help on this please? Edit Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/91fgth2f/8/**

```js
var audio;

//Hide Pause Initially

$('#pause').hide();
$('#playlist').hide();



//Initializer - Play First Song
initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

function initAudio(element) {
  var song = element.attr('song');
  var title = element.text();
  var cover = element.attr('cover');
  var artist = element.attr('artist');

  //Create a New Audio Object
  audio = new Audio('media/' + song);

  if (!audio.currentTime) {
    $('#duration').html('0.00');
  }

  $('#audio-player .title').text(title);
  $('#audio-player .artist').text(artist);

  //Insert Cover Image
  $('img.cover').attr('src', 'images/covers/' + cover);

  $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
  element.addClass('active');
}


//Play Button
$('#play').click(function() {
  audio.play();
  $('#play').hide();
  $('#pause').show();
  $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
  showDuration();
});

//Pause Button
$('#pause').click(function() {
  audio.pause();
  $('#pause').hide();
  $('#play').show();
});

//Stop Button
$('#stop').click(function() {
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  $('#pause').hide();
  $('#play').show();
  $('#duration').fadeOut(400);
});

//Next Button
$('#next').click(function() {
  audio.pause();
  var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
  if (next.length == 0) {
    next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
  }
  initAudio(next);
  audio.play();
  showDuration();
});
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #000000;
  background: url(../images/bg.png);
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#audio-image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
#audio-info {
  text-align: center;
}
#audio-info .artist {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.cover {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
input#volume {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}
input#volume::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: url(../images/knob.png) no-repeat;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
#buttons {
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 23px;
  overflow: auto;
}
button#play {
  width: 24px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url(../images/play.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
button#pause {
  width: 24px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url(../images/pause.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
button#stop {
  width: 24px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url(../images/stop.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
button#prev {
  width: 24px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url(../images/prev.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
button#next {
  width: 24px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url(../images/next.png) no-repeat;
  float: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#playlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 2px;
}
#playlist li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
#tracker {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#playlist li.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #666;
}
#progressBar {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  height: 5px;
  background: url(../images/progress_bg.png) no-repeat;
  float: right;
}
#progress {
  background: url(../images/progress.png) no-repeat;
  height: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#duration {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -25px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

    <!---It plays for the songs within the first nested: <ul> </ul>-->

    <tr>

      <td align="left">

        <div class="buttons">

          <span>      
      <button id="play"></button>
     <button id="pause"></button>
      <button id="next"></button>
    </span>


          <ul id="playlist" class="hidden">

            <li song="song1.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Artist1">Title.mp3</li>

            <!--- next song (song2.mp3) plays if added within this first nested: <ul> </ul> -->
            <li song="song2.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Artist2">Title2.mp3</li>

          </ul>

        </div>

      </td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: Where you load jQuery library?

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1 from my local machine linked to the html. Here is the live code: https://github.com/bradtraversy/html5audioplayer/blob/master/js/jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

Problem on calling the 
`initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));`

in above code u are passing first li element try to change the code like `initAudio($('#playlist li'));`.

Hope this will work

Comment: Thanks Aamir - It's one of the errors, I've changed it but still not working.

Comment: Hi @Charlie, Can u add class 'active' to currently playing something like element.addClass('active').

Comment: It didn't work for me, can you try it with the fiddle pls: http://jsfiddle.net/91fgth2f/8/